# SQL COUNT returning wrong value with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm currently writing a query to search over three tables (invoice, job_lines and item_records). job_lines and item_records both have multiple entries per invoice.id so I'm trying to combine them into one line per id.

It seems to be working so far but the count(*) is giving back the number of item_records.MAWB/item_records.HAWB per line rather than the overall number of grouped entries.

is there a way to get the actual total number of groups?

```
SELECT      

        COUNT(*), 
        invoice.id,   
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT job_lines.job_number SEPARATOR ' '),''),   
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_records.MAWB SEPARATOR ' '),''),   
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_records.HAWB SEPARATOR ' '),'')    
FROM      

        invoice   
LEFT JOIN job_lines ON invoice.id=job_lines.taken   
LEFT JOIN item_records ON invoice.job_number=item_records.job_number  
GROUP BY

        invoice.id
```

Example data:

Id  Job Number  HAWB    MAWB
1|  200001 |    a1,a2,a3 |  b2,b3
2|  200002 |    a7, a8, |   b1
3|  255544 |    a11   | b4

Im after the total number of ID's in this case, but im getting the total number of HAWB/MAWB from each line.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, but Gareth's answer explain the problem and the typical solution.

Answer (score 1):

You count joined records per invoice.id . So if you have for an invoice id 5 job lines and 3 item records, you get 5 x 3 = 15.

If you want just the number of job lines, use `COUNT(DISTINCT job_lines.id)`.

If you want just the number of item records, use `COUNT(DISTINCT item_records.id)`.

Comment: currently using COUNT(DISTINCT invoice.id) gives me a result of 1, even though it returns 3 lines. COUNT(DISTINCT job_lines.id) and COUNT(DISTINCT item_records.id) return the correct number of sub lines but I'm after the overall total.

Comment: Would the overall total not just one plus the other though? i.e. `COUNT(DISTINCT job_lines.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT item_records.id)`

Comment: Sorry I think I must have worded this rather badly, what I'm after is the number of groups, COUNT(DISTINCT job_lines.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT item_records.id) would just give me the number of sublines per group.

Comment: Of course `COUNT(DISTINCT invoice.id)` always gives you 1 per invoice_id (which you group by). So my example given, 5 job lines and 3 item records for an invoice_id, what number would you like to see? Not 5x3=15, not 5, not 3, not 5+3=8. So what else?

Comment: I need the number of invoice.id's then, I'm grouping by invoice.id but how do I count the number of groups in total?

Comment: This would be another query. One gives you the list of invoices with their Job numbers etc., say 10000 lines. Another query would give you the number 10000. Of course you could select 10000 lines and each has a column containing the number 10000, but what sense would that make? However, if you really wanted to do that, you would replace `COUNT(*)` with `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoice)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform your aggregates in subqueries, what you are currently doing is causing a cross join, so if there are 2 records in `job_lines` and 2 records in `item_records` for a particular invoice id, you end up with 4 rows covering all 4 combinations.

```
SELECT  jl.Count + ir.Count AS Count,
        i.id,
        IFNULL(jl.JobLines, ''),
        IFNULL(ir.MAWB, '') AS MAWB AS JobLines,
        IFNULL(ir.HAWB, '') AS HAWB
FROM    Invoice AS i
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  taken, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(job_number SEPARATOR ' ') AS JobLines,
                    COUNT(*) AS Count
            FROM    job_lines
            GROUP BY taken
        ) AS jl
            ON jl.taken = i.id
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  job_number, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(item_records.MAWB SEPARATOR ' ') AS MAWB,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(item_records.HAWB SEPARATOR ' ') AS HAWB,
                    COUNT(*) AS Count
            FROM    item_records
            GROUP BY job_number
        ) AS ir
            ON ir.job_number = i.job_number;
```

N.B. MySQL Materialises subqueries, i.e. will perform each of the subqueries once when they are first referenced, and store the results in a hashed temporary table and look up from that each time. So if you were to have a WHERE clause that that meant only a limited number of invoices were returned, it would be inefficient to summarise the entire `job_lines` table into a temporary table, only to use a few records. If this is the case then Thorsten's answer will be more efficient, however if you are querying a large amount of the invoice table, then not having to use DISTINCT to undo the cross join should prove more efficient.